# Flush $timeout in protractor

Tags: angularjs, protractor, angularjs-ngmock

I'm writing test using protractor and it always waits when *$timeout* will finished.

If I use **ignoreSynchronization = true;** it stops to wait and test runs ahead. But for my test I should set back **ignoreSynchronization = false;**. And when I set it to false, protractor stops and begin to wait for previous *$timeout* will finished.

I use *$timeout* for notification window and use this window to show validation errors. Currently I'm testing validation and it makes test extremely slow.

So the solution with *ingnoreSynchronization = true* is not compatible for me.

I have tried to *$timeout.flush()* but it cause an error *$timeout.flush is not a function*

I tried to use [ngMock](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock) but am not sure is it possible to use it with protractor.

Does somebody resolve this issue?

Comment: why is `ignoreSynchronization = true` not an option for you?

Comment: The architecture you are describing doesn't make sense.  What does "I use `$timeout` for notification window...." actually mean?  Why would you force angular to *wait* when you want to pop up a notification?  You have tightly coupled your app logic to a UI thread by doing this this way, which is a code smell, and the slowness in your tests are also going to manifest as slowness for your users.  Seems like the unit tests have done their job in identifying a place to consider a major refactor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same exact issue. We are using timeouts on our notification UI and it was pausing the app every time we displayed a notifications till it dismissed itself. This worked for us:

Protractor allows you to inject modules from your tests. So what we did was move our timeout duration argument into a `constant`, that could be set to 0 when running protractor tests.

*In your module:*

```
.constant('NOTIFICATION_CONSTANTS', {
  TIMEOUT_DURATION: 5000
})

.controller('NotificationController', function($scope, NOTIFICATION_CONSTANTS) 
{
  $scope.showNotification = function() {
    $timeout(function() { hideNotification(); }, NOTIFICATION_CONSTANTS.TIMEOUT_DURATION)
  };
})
```

*in your protractor test:*

```
...
beforeAll(function() {
  browser.addMockModule('testConfig', function() {
    angular.module('testConfig', []).run(function(NOTIFICATION_CONSTANTS) {
      NOTIFICATION_CONSTANTS.TIMEOUT_DURATION = 0;
    });
  });
});
...
```

It wont dismiss all $timeouts by default, but if they're created by you and you know which ones you want to dismiss you can target them like this.

Answer (score 1):

Protractor is supposed to wait for any $timeout or $http calls to finish before executing, as part of synchronization with the Angular app.  Since you use $timeout continuously, you have a few options:

1. Change your $timeout to use $interval instead.  Source: [Protractor Timeouts](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/timeouts.md)
2. Adjust your config file to account for $timeout, taken from the [Protractor Master Conf](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/referenceConf.js):

> Protractor will track outstanding $timeouts by default, and report them in 
>     the error message if Protractor fails to synchronize with Angular in time. 
>     In order to do this Protractor needs to decorate $timeout. 
>     CAUTION: If your app decorates $timeout, you must turn on this flag. This 
>     is false by default.
>     `untrackOutstandingTimeouts: false`,

3. Set `browser.ignoreSynchronization = true` to treat your app as "Non-Angular" and use Expected Conditions to wait for certain elements to be present before executing the test.  Source: [Expected Conditions](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ProtractorExpectedConditions)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are not waiting the resolution of the promise to set `ignoreSynchronization` to `true` or `false`. I would try to push a function on the control flow to set the property:

```
// disable the synchronization
browser.controlFlow().execute(function() {
  browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;
});

// execute some asynchronous code
...

// enable the synchronization
browser.controlFlow().execute(function() {
  browser.ignoreSynchronization = false;
});
```